# How to use certain cells from a HTML table and placed into a new table

Tags: php, html, html-table, include

I have a HTML table (saved as from Excel) now how do i take certain cells/data information from this HTML table and display the same data into another HTML table (but placed in a different order). I assume I would have to use PHP if so how does one get round this?

Comment: This question is way to broad. What is your current code, what have you tried already?

Comment: At the moment its a basic HTML table (File named: Report001.html) displaying numbers the following information:  Row 1: 200 | 2333 | 45% | 6767.00. Row 2: 400 | 5000 | 88% | 412.00. Now this table will eventually be bigger. But all I need is to create another web page (file name Results.html) and link some of this data seen above into a new table for example only display in Row 1: 200 | 45% Row 2: 400 | 88%. Now the data from the original table from the file name: Report001.html if this gets updated with different number this will update the Results.html automatically. - hope this helps?